# Lucifer (TV series) devilface in Season 3 Episode 7

Tags: vertigo-comics, lucifer-2016

In the TV series Lucifer, Season 3's big drama is that Lucifer looses his devil face, but his angel wings grow back even if he cuts them off. In Episode 7 the turning point of the plot comes when he actually shows his devil face to the man being interrogated, and he himself also clearly sees it in the mirror. Since then I've watched the later episodes up to 10 and the only mentions about his devil face are comments about him not having it, with no mention of it appearing on him. Does anybody know what the explanation for this is? It really bugs me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Episode [A Good day to Die](http://lucifer.wikia.com/wiki/A_Good_Day_to_Die), we get our first true glimpse of what Hell is like for the dammed. They relive the sin(s) that put them there for all eternity.

In the episode you're talking about, [Off the Record](http://lucifer.wikia.com/wiki/Off_the_Record), we learn that

> Lucifer is not responsible for sending humans to Hell, they do it to themselves out of guilt

Major Spoiler Ahead. I will tag it appropriately, but if you have not seen the episode and don't want it ruined, don't look!

> [Reese Getty](http://lucifer.wikia.com/wiki/Reese_Getty) became aware of the relationship between Lucifer and Dr. Linda sometime during the first season. He became obsessed and started following/stalking Lucifer. Ultimately this resulted in Reese being killed and sending himself to Hell.

Therefore

> The entire episode is from the point of view of Reese, in Hell, reliving what he did to get there and covers events from the first season onward. He saw the devil face BEFORE Lucifer lost it.

Comment: Ok, I'm planning to watch the remaining episodes today or tomorrow, I'll read it when I catch up :D

Comment: The spoilers are limited to Episodes you've already seen. Rewatch the one in particular you are asking about and the answer should be clear

Comment: Hmm, it is really hard to make a follow up comment without ruining your spoiler tags :) But basically you are saying that the first part of the Episode happens sometime in timeline Season 1 and the second half happens at its place in Season 3? Yes, that makes sense :)